# OpenVino toolkit training repo and pre-trained models

Tags: openvino

Under the openvinotoolkit is a repo for training [deepReID](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/deep-object-reid)  and there are a number of projects such as training a model for [person attributes](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/deep-object-reid/tree/ote/projects/attribute_recognition)

1. Is this the codebase that was used to train the pre-trained models provided with OpenVino?
2. Is it possible to provide a script to show how to obtain the pre-trained models using the code?
3. The person attribute uses a dataset with more attributes than provided by the pre-trained model. Is there an updated model using this repo?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Deep-object-reid](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/deep-object-reid) uses Torchreid. Torchreid is a library for deep-learning person re-identification, written in PyTorch. This toolkit allows developers to deploy pre-trained deep learning models through a high-level C++ Inference Engine API integrated with application logic.
2. You can download the pretrained models from [Open Model Zoo](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo) by going to the directory:
   *openvino/deployment_tools/open_model_zoo/tools/downloader*

   Then, run the following command to download pre-trained models:
   *./downloader.py --name <model_name>*
   For more details, please visit this [page](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.2/omz_tools_downloader_README.html).
3. This [repo](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/deep-object-reid/tree/ote/projects/attribute_recognition) is forked from [KaiyangZhou/deep-person-reid.](https://github.com/KaiyangZhou/deep-person-reid)

Comment: Thanks but I was looking to train my models and as a start I would like to be able to train an existing model all the way from the Torchreid to the OpenVino framework (so I would like to first reproduce a pretrained model). In addition to this I would like to understand if the person attributes repo produced an openvino model( there seems to be many more attributes in the dataset here than in the pretrained model).